# <PrivateRoute> with changed path not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to extend `<Route>` component of `react-router-dom` so it would prepend some value before `path` property. It would look like this:

```
export default function MyRoute({path, ...rest}) {
    const newpath = '/app' + path;
    return <Route path={newpath} {...rest} />
}
```

I want to use it like:

```
<MyRoute path="/login" component={Login} />
```

So behind the scenes it should render:

```
<Route path="/app/login" component={Login} />
```

When I go to `/app/login` url it doesn't load. `<Login />` still shows up only on `/login`.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit**

It doesn't work when used directly inside `<Switch>`:

```
<Switch>
    <MyRoute path="/login" />
</Switch>
```

But works when moved to another component:

```
<Switch>
    <Routes />
</Switch>
```

and Routes beeing:

```
<>
    <MyRoute path="/login" />
</>
```

Comment: you can consider using `basename` prop on `Router`, or using nested routing with first points `app` path, and then using `path` from `match` react-router-dom props on whole the child routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using following code:

```
index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    
    <!-- Below we can set subpage containing React app -->
    <script>window.react_app_url = '/my-app-page'</script>
    
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Custom `<MyRoute>` is supposed to override all `path` attributes to include `react_app_url` defined in index.html. Ex. `<MyRoute path="/home" />` should change into `<Route path="/my-app-page/home" />`.

```
MyRoute.js

import React from 'react';

export default function MyRoute({path, ...rest}) {
    let appUrl = '';
    if(window.hasOwnProperty('react_app_url')) {
        appUrl = window.react_app_url;
    }

    if( Array.isArray(path) ) {
        const paths = path.map(singlepath=>`${appUrl}${singlepath}`);
        path = paths;
    } else {
        path = appUrl + path;
    }
    return <Route path={path} {...rest} />;
}
```

In `App.js` we can now use custom `<Routes>` inside `<Switch>` and all `paths` will be replaced from, ex. `/home` to `/my-app-page/home`.

```
App.js

import React from 'react';

import {BrowserRouter, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import MyRoute from './MyRoute';

export default function App() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <>
                    <MyRoute path="/home" component={Home} />
                    <MyRoute path="/about" component={About} />
                    <MyRoute path="/contact" component={Contact} />
                </>
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```